# A static list expression is required for depends_on

Tags: terraform

```
locals {
package1 = [A, B, C, D]
package2 = [A, B, C]
app_package = local.does_exist ? package1 : package2
}

resource "capability" "this_is_a_name" {
name = somename
depends_on = local.app_package
}
```

The depends on shows error: A static list expression is required.

There are two situations for app_package, so I use local.does_exist to determine which one should it use.
I want to have a static list in depends_on but don't know how to do it.

Comment: You can't, it is what error message communicates to you. Some meta-args (module, provider, depends_on and several other) can't be dynamic and must be a direct static value.

Comment: Thank you! Any idea how to let it work in my situation?

Answer (score 0):

The `depends_on` argument declares explicit *static* dependencies between objects declared in the configuration. "Static" here means "before any expression evaluation", which is important because the dependency graph is how Terraform decides which order to evaluate the expressions in. The dependency graph must therefore be decided before evaluating any expressions.

However, because these are dependencies between *static* objects, you also don't need to worry about any dynamic decisions about how many instances they have. For example:

```
resource "aws_instance" "example_a" {
  count = var.a_count
}

resource "aws_instance" "example_b" {
  count = var.c_count
}

resource "aws_instance" "example_c" {
  depends_on = [
    aws_instance.example_a,
    aws_instance.example_b,
  ]
}
```

The above declares that everything in the `resource "aws_instance" "example_c"` block depends on *all instances of* both `resource "aws_instance" "example_a"` and `resource "aws_instance" "example_b"`. If it turns out that either one of those has `count = 0` after evaluation, that doesn't change the dependency graph: Terraform still needs to know that needs to evaluate *the `count` expression* of the first two resources before it can do any evaluation of the third one, at which point it will know that both `aws_instance.example_a` and `aws_instance.example_b` are empty lists.

Your given example is sufficiently contrived/invalid that I'm not sure how to understand what you intended, but here's a similarly contrived/invalid example that I hope illustrates that you can just list out all of the configuration objects that the resource depends on, regardless of any dynamic decisions they might be making about instance counts:

```
  depends_on = [A, B, C, D, XYZ]
```